# Using a pipe symbol in typing.Literal string

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, typechecking

I have a function that accepts certain literals for a specific argument:

```
from typing import Literal

def fn(x: Literal["foo", "bar", "foo|bar"]) -> None:
    reveal_type(x)
```

The third contains a pipe symbol (`|`), `"foo|bar"`. This is interpreted by `mypy` as an error, as the name `foo` is not defined.

I guess this happens due to how forward references are evaluated? I use Python 3.8 with:

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

Is there a way to make this work? I can not change the string due to breaking backward compatibility, but currently, the whole annotation is revealed as `Any`, i.e. it holds no value.

Comment: It would be helpful, too, if in your [mre] you showed the mypy usage you're using to demonstrate that "the whole annotation is revealed as `Any`"

Comment: Is this what you mean: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=1.6.1&python=3.11&flags=show-error-context&gist=824684e15baf367b67f5c4197681d76e ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is a bug in mypy. Other type checkers (pyright, PyCharm inspections) can handle this without issue. I don't see an [existing issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues) for it, so it would be worth reporting

Comment: Going by how, by design, [`Literal['Color.RED']` interprets `'Color.RED'` as a string instead of a forward reference](https://peps.python.org/pep-0586/#literals-enums-and-forward-references), I think mypy should be changed to interpret `"foo|bar"` as a string instead of a forward reference here too.

Comment: I see. I'll open an issue if this question does not receive a possible workaround/solution within a few days.

Comment: You should do that anyway. It’s a bug.

Comment: @HåkonT. I filed one: [#16367](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/16367).